# Count of unique identifier based on 2 columns sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, having

I have a simple question! I need to calculate how many user_id's attended multiple events (confirmed or registered). There are 24 distinct event id's in the real dataset. Here is my query that did not provide me the results I was looking for: Where did I go wrong? This is done in BigQuery if that info was needed.

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) as volunteer_count,
  status, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) as event_count
FROM `nice-incline.events_participations.events_participations`
WHERE status = 'CONFIRMED' OR status = 'REGISTERED'
GROUP BY status
HAVING event_count > 1;
```

Below is a sample table.

| event_id | user_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 378398 | 1783965 | confirmed |
| 418729 | 4518485 | registered |
| 378398 | 4518485 | registered |
| 418729 | 4432831 | canceled |

The expected results would be just be a count of user_id's who have attended multiple (>1) event_id's. So in this case, we would only have 1 since user '4518485' attended 2 events and they are registered

Comment: what would be th expected result

Comment: first, try to fix WHERE clause to `WHERE UPPER(status) IN ('CONFIRMED', 'REGISTERED')`; secondly - clarify logic and expected output

Comment: Made all those changes and expected output!

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
select count(*) from (
  select user_id 
  from your_table
  where status in ('confirmed', 'registered')
  group by user_id
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

or (with same output)

```
select count(*) from (
  select distinct user_id
  from your_table
  where status in ('confirmed', 'registered')
  qualify count(*) over(partition by user_id) > 1
)
```